# C# - How to get the value of a passed lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda

I have a special case. I need to rewrite a library and I do not have the original code. To make the discussion clearer lets call the library HandlerLibOld and HandlerLibNew.

I want to make HandlerLibNew that shall replace HandlerLibOld.

I have an application that uses this library, and it is big application with 1000s of calls to the library.
I rather not have to change the application code.

**Sample application code**

```
public class MyMessage : MyBaseClass
{
   public int ValueA {get;set;}
   public int ValueB {get;set;}
}
public class MyOtherMessage : MyBaseClass
{
   public int ValueC {get;set;}
   public int ValueD {get;set;}
}

public class Sender
{
   Handler handler = new Handler();
   handler.Send<MyMessage>(m => { m.ValueA=10; m.ValueB=20; });
}
```

Notice the line `handler.Send<MyMessage>(m => { m.ValueA=10; m.ValueB=20; });`. It uses a lambda expression to define an object of the `MyMessage` and sets two properties of this object. Notice that I rather not have to change this code.

Maybe I have misunderstood what the lambda expression does, but the point is I need to tell the Handler.Send about the values ValueA and ValueB.

Now I want to write the implementation of the `Send` method of the `Handler`. The tricky part is that the lambda expression makes it an action, but I want to get the MyMessage object instance. How can I achieve that? Do I need to use reflection somehow?

**My attempts**

I have tried:

```
public class Handler
{
    public void Send<T>(Action<T> actionmessage)
    {
        // actionmessage is an object of type Action<T>, 
        // I want to get the object of type T that was passed into the method.
    }
}
```

I have also tried:

```
public class Handler
{
    public void Send<T>(T message)
    {
         // This will not compile. I get:
         //    Cannot convert lambda expression 
         //    to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type
    }
}
```

I know it is possible somehow because this works with the HandlerLibOld. How can I achieve the same with HandlerLibNew? I don't have access to the code of HandlerLibOld.

Comment: `actionmessage` can do whatever it likes to the object passed in; you have no control over this, nor can you (easily) reflect over it, as the code is compiled IL. The only thing you can reasonably do with it is invoke it (`actionmessage(message)`). You can wrap the delegate in your own to perform actions before or after the delegate is invoked, but that's about it. As to how and why and when you'd invoke it (i.e. when you get the `message`), that can't be determined from the interface alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for that Action to work, you must have an **instance of T** to begin with:

```
public void Send<T>(Action<T> actionMessage)
        where T: new()
    {
        var input = new T();
        actionMessage(input);
        //T has now valueA and valueB populated
        //do more with input T
        //send
    }
```

Now if T were to have a constraint such as implementing a certain interface, you can do more stuff on the object itself. If you are using base classes you must be careful with object slicing.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for! Thank you!